# Is casting free() argument to void * neccessary?

Tags: c, malloc, free

Is it neccessary to cast the value passed to `free()` to a void pointer in this code snippet?

```
free((void *) np->defn);
```

`np` is a `struct` in a linked list and `defn` is a `char *`.

Comment: No, `free` wants a `(const void *)` cast when a pointer is declared as `const`, for non-const pointers you don't need a cast

Comment: @AlterMann: presumably it would want a non const cast...

Comment: @KeineLust Actually the parameter type, as defined by the Standard, is `void *`. It would be an error to try and pass a `const void *`.

Comment: @M.M you are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### C11 : 7.22.3.3 The free function

> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```

It means that it can take pointer to any type (`void *` is a generic pointer type). In general no need to cast the argument to `void *`, but in cases like

```
int const *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
free(a);
```

compiler will generate a waring

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:33:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  free(a);
       ^
In file included from test.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:151:7: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'const int *'
 void  free(void *);
       ^
```

To suppress this warning a cast is needed

```
 free((void *)a);
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why its in the C Programming Language 2nd edition. Maybe it was different many moons ago.

Comment: This answer is only correct if `stdlib.h` has been included, or a correct prototype for `free`  otherwise given

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. If `stdlib.h` has *not* been included, and we are in [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89) mode, then the cast is necessary. This is because: when calling a function without any prototype in scope, the argument types (after default argument promotion) must match the actual parameter types of the function implementation.

Of course, a better solution is to include `stdlib.h` and ensure that compiler diagnostics are enabled to alert you in case you call `free` without a prototype in scope.

In the [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) days (even second edition) it was still common practice to call functions without a prototype in scope.

---

Another point, not mentioned in any answer so far, is that people sometimes use `const T *` to hold an owning pointer to dynamically allocated memory.  If `np->defn` had the type `const int *`, for example, then it is necessary to cast away the `const`, even if `stdlib.h` was included. And casting to `void *` is a simple way to achieve that.

This is because the prototype for `free` is `void free(void *ptr);`, and C does not permit implicit conversions to remove `const` from behind a pointer.

You did specify in the question that it was non-const `char *`; however the coder might sometimes use both and be in the habit of always casting (since there is really no down-side other than obeying general coding guidelines to avoid redundant casts).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you should not need to cast to `(void *)`.

Someone asked in a comment if any compiler gave a warning in the absence of the cast, and got the response "a broken one, perhaps".

Well, GCC 4.8.4 seems to be broken in that case

```
usr/include/stdlib.h:483:13: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
```

Compiler version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It causes no harm to add the cast, and avoids the temptation to disable that warning -- and thus miss a real bug.

Comment: Note that it is the code which is broken and not the compiler

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Though doing so will probably prevent warning errors given by your compiler.

```
free(void *);
```

The function `free` will free any memory that is allocated with malloc. All it needs for that is the memory address returned by `malloc`. So as long as `np->defn` has a memory value that was returned by malloc you should be fine.

Comment: Is there any compiler giving a warning without the cast?

Comment: @mafso: a broken one, perhaps.

Comment: @mafso: I wasn't sure if it gave an warning on -Wall. But it doesn't so there is no need at all to cast.