# Casting to void * before freeing memory (C programming)

Tags: c, casting, free, void-pointers

I came across this code and wondering why it has been casted to `void *` before freeing?

```
free((void *)array1[i]);
```

I have seen `free` used without casting in some articles, so I'm wondering why you would cast to `void *` when freeing memory?

Here's how they have allocated and freed memory:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array1 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    array1[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));

for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    free((void *)array1[i]);
free((void *)array1);
```

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339569/casting-free-argument-to-void), some gcc version may throw a warning but overall it's unnecessary.

Comment: It's probably c++.

Comment: dave558, Curious, in this case, what type was `array1[i]`?  Was the allocation for it also employed a cast?

Answer (score 8):

That cast is nonsense in C.

It might be that they are compiling the code in a C++ compiler, in which case the cast is needed. But compiling C code with a C++ compiler is not a good idea in general.

Comment: Even in C++ the cast isn't needed. [Life demo](https://www.ideone.com/Tlf1y0). Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Ah, come to think of it I believe C++ does not allow implicit conversion from `void*` to `type*`, but the other way around is ok.

Comment: It could be that the code is in a header file that's used in both C and C++ projects. I have a header file library or two that I made C++ compatible for the occasional use in a C++ project (though I much prefer C).

Comment: I suppose it could also be there to cast away qualifiers, In which case the code is fishy, no matter C or C++.

Comment: Some people feel that it aids const-correctness to use a `const T *` for the case where a dynamically allocated object has its value set upon allocation and is not to be modified thereafter